# how to display long string using .innerHTML on IE

Tags: javascript, variables, internet-explorer-11, limit, innerhtml

How can I have .innerHTML to display long string on IE? How can I change that limit on the page, so that it would behave the same as Chrome, and 271740 would not be cut off by IE? As for the example below, the line number 271740 would show on Chrome, but not on IE 11.

```js
var sTempry='';
for(var y=0;y<271741;y++){sTempry=sTempry+y+'<br>';}
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=sTempry;
```

```html
<div id='display'></div>
```

Someone claims that this question is an exact duplicate question of string limitation, but as I dig deeper, that might not be the case for IE has a HIGHER string limitation then Chrome, and I wrote another code to separate the size of the variable string. But still, the same problem persist, the '271740' appears on Chrome but not on IE.

```js
var sTempry='';
for(var y=0;y<150000;y++){sTempry=sTempry+y+'<br>';}

var sTempry2='';
for(var y=150000;y<271741;y++){sTempry2=sTempry2+y+'<br>';}
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=sTempry+sTempry2;
```

```html
<div id='display'></div>
```

As someone suggested, I tried another code to proof that it is not hitting the variable limit. Again, 271740 appears on Chrome, but not on IE:

```js
var sTempry='';
for(var y=0;y<150000;y++){sTempry=sTempry+y+'<br>';}
var el = document.getElementById('display');
el.innerHTML = sTempry; 

var sTempry2='';
for(var y=150000;y<271741;y++){sTempry2=sTempry2+y+'<br>';}
el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", sTempry2);
```

```html
<div id='display'></div>
```

Comment: May I ask what the use case is for putting 271,741 lines of text into a single HTML element? This seems to be a "I want a web browser to work _just like_ MS Word (or Excel, or PPT, etc)"

Comment: If `<br>` is the only HTML, you could start by trying to make the `div` into `pre`, using regular line breaks, and setting the `pre` element's `.innerText`.

Comment: I tried to display a page dynamically and I found that IE display differently then Chrome. As I dig deeper on the problem source. I found that the problem came from the .innerHTML could not display long string on IE as much as Chrome. I came up this example to simulate my problem, to make the problem easy to see and understand

Comment: The last example doesn't really tell you that it isn't a string size problem. Your `sTempry+sTempry2` is still creating a single string of a large size. Did you try appending the strings separately? `var el = document.getElementById('display'); el.innerHTML = sTempry; el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", sTempry2);`

Comment: I'll try your code, but I checked that my IE support variable size 4000MB, while Chrome support variable size 2000MB, which opposed the conclusion of hitting the variable limit.  If it hit the variable limit, I should hit the limit, on Chrome before IE, for Chrome has half as much of variable memory size. But my example shows IE stop much earlier than Chrome

Comment: @doodlemeister, but your .insertAdjacentHTML example doesn't show that the problem is not caused by any limitation on .innerHTML.  In order to proof that the problem I have make code the long string manually... And have the .innerHTML take the entire string at once...

Comment: Of course not. I'm just responding to your assertion that you've proven that it isn't a string length problem. It could be, and it could also be an `.innerHTML` problem. Ultimately, any string length problem will also present a problem for a single call to `.innerHTML`, since it relies on a string, so I don't see the importance in separating them.

Comment: @doodlemeister, Thank you for your reply.  I tried your code, same result. And I added that code on to my original question. The result is that it is still not showing on IE.

Comment: @doodlemeister, do you have IE. Would you confirm if you see 271740 on your IE? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @doodlemeister, as I think of your replies, It might be the page limit also. Might be that .innerHTML can display the entire string but IE has a page length limit and not displaying it... Just a wild thought...

Comment: Sorry, I can't confirm this for you. If the result still doesn't show, the next thing I'd try would be to not use `.innerHTML` at all, but rather create the DOM elements manually.

Comment: @doodlemeister, did 471740 show up on your IE? Right now, I am collecting any info I can get. Thank you very much!

Comment: Again, I am not able to confirm this for you. Best of luck!

Comment: @doodlemeister, Thank you!